# ¿Cómo soluciono este error a la hora de instalar OnOff con npm y NodeJS para una RPI3?

Tags: npm, raspberry-pi

Estoy tratando de instalar las herramientas de OnOff para poder manipular los pines GPIO de mi Raspberry PI 3 B+ y poder encender y apagar un led, el código correría con JavaScript, la configuración inicial se hace instalando Node.JS y Npm en la Raspberry y con ello se usa `npm install onoff` para descargar el módulo. Puedo analizar que tiene que ver con permisos, me gustaría saber qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo. Este es el reporte que sale al intentar la instalación:

```
root@PabloRPI:/home/pi/Documents/nodetest# npm install onoff

> epoll@2.0.9 install /home/pi/node_modules/epoll
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/8.16.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/home/pi/node_modules/epoll/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/pi/node_modules/epoll/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.14.98-v7+
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/node_modules/epoll
gyp ERR! node -v v8.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/package.json'
npm WARN pi No description
npm WARN pi No repository field.
npm WARN pi No README data
npm WARN pi No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! epoll@2.0.9 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the epoll@2.0.9 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-18T23_39_42_268Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Perdona mi ignorancia sobre Raspberry PI 3 pero creo que el nucleo es linux, ¿no?
Y a lo mejor ya lo has hecho pero... ¿has probado a ejecutar ese comando en modo superusuario?

```
>sudo epoll@2.0.9 install /home/pi/node_modules/epoll
>sudo node-gyp rebuild
```